# Plotting using python for large datasets

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, loops, data-analysis

I have a large dataset of around 1000 values in 2 columns. These values are separated by spaces for example 500 in the first set and the next 500 in another set (image below).

[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlB1f.png)

I am stuck on how to make a loop that plots the data (x,y) till it encounters the first space and then does a second plot and so on.

I tried this to get the plots but I don't know how to separate the plots with space in between.

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    plt.plot(x[i],y[i])
plt.show()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].